# How to get a quick answer whether an image is prefetched before attempting to download it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, react-native, caching, electron

**What do I need:** something like [React Native's Image.queryCache()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.54/image#querycache), but working with browser cache (I'm working with Electron, so Chrome in this case).

**How does this `queryCache()` work:** it checks if the resources from URLs given are present in the native cache and returns the result (in React Native it's implemented for Android/iOS, I need something similar for web/Electron). It's relatively quick, because it doesn't attempt to download them (what might take some time). If I create an image in JS, there's an attempt to download it and only after I get the answer if it succeeded.

**Why do I need it:** My app displays many emoticons (relatively small images) in various places. E.g. if an emoticon can't be fetched or it could take too much time, a smaller version (also available to download) of it or a placeholder should be displayed until it's not fully fetched. Generally the idea is to create a custom logic for caching emoticons to make it more reliable.

There are a few similar questions with answers out there, but none of them provide a satisfactory solution, let me mention a few of them:

1. Solution presented in the snippet below. The problem here is that checking if an image is cached it's not immediate. Also, the time of the operation might vary depending on the size of the image, so timer solutions don't seem convincing as well.

   ```js
   function() { 
       var img = new Image();
       img.src = "some url";
       return img.complete;
   }
   ```
2. Second solution I found is to create a `localStorage` entry when prefetching succeeds. The problem here is how to update the storage when the browser removes the image from the cache?

There's also a `CacheStorage` API available which looks promising, but the question is how to make it cooperate with the browser cache? I mean, e.g. in one place I'm creating an `inline-block` element with a `background-image` CSS property I provide an URL to and I'm wondering how it could be applied here.

If it turns out a satisfactory solution doesn't exist, this kind of information might be useful as well :)

Comment: You will want to look into using Service Workers, you can control how the cache behaves.. -> https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker